# My jQuery's getJSON result is not in order

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a SQL query which get my playlist ordered by tag and name :
`SELECT * FROM playlist WHERE iduser=9 ORDER BY tag,name ASC;`

Result :

| iduser | idplaylist | name | tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | PL74A6S2w9aDA-Gdnhb7b58wRSjYo7t9LK | AlphaCast : Table Quest | Comedy |
| 9 | PL1UBPUKVQV3qV0o9W1Yy0H8krB1IvhC1R | AlphaCast : Baldurs gate 3 | Gaming |
| 9 | PL1UBPUKVQV3oRu-NanDuXxFxMUR1li9XU | AlphaCast : The Witcher 3 | Gaming |
| 9 | PLUUOiZvrsOA-vaRZTFWPPd4Xij_LhmePy | Lore Starcraft | Gaming |

I send this result row by row to a JavaScript function which aims to use the Youtube API and get a JSON for each idplaylist and send this JSON to another JavaScript function.

**The problem** is that when I use `$.getJSON` by idplaylist, the JSON I get are not in the same order than the table result above.

The code :

```
<?php
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM playlist WHERE iduser=? ORDER BY tag,name ASC;";
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $_SESSION["iduser"]);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
   $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $playlistid = $row['idplaylist'];
      $playlistname = $row['name'];
      $playlisttag = $row['tag'];
      echo "<script>displayplaylist('$playlistid', '$playlistname', '$playlisttag');</script>";
   }
?>
```

```
function displayplaylist(playlistid, playlistname, playlisttag) {
   var key = '';
   var playlistId = playlistid;
   var URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems';

   var options = {
     part: 'snippet',
     key: key,
     maxResults: 50,
     playlistId: playlistId
   }

   $.getJSON(URL, options function (data) {
     resultplaylist(data, playlistname, playlisttag);
     resultvideos(data, playlistid);               
   });
}
```

Comment: This is because AJAX is asynchronous. The order the responses come back to your are indeterminate at runtime. If you require the data to be sorted I would suggest you aggregate all the response data in to a single array, sort that, then display.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I fixed the problem by using $.ajax with parameter async: false.
It's a little bit more slower but at least I get all my result in the good order.